# recursively turn massive JSON to a html list

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I have been trying for a week to turn a HUGE javascript object to an unordered list. the function I have right now doesnt right. it returns only the first layer. the rest it doesnt. freezing of the browser is also a problem which my solution is to use setTimeout(function,0);

JSON format:

```
{
"name": "",
"value": { //JSON always start with these 2. content is inside this value key.
    "randomname": {
        "type": "list",
        "value": {
            "type": "int", //another type and value to that is in the array
            "value": [26, 32, 25]
        }
    },
    "randomname": {
        "type": "int",
        "value": 5
    },
    "randomname": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "string or something"
    },
    "randomname": {
        "type": "compound", //compound types can be inside compound types can be inside compount types etc.
        "value": {
            "randomname": {
                "type": "int",
                "value": 6

            },
            "randomname": {
                "type": "int",
                "value": 6

            }
        }
    },
    "randomname": {
        "type": "long",
        "value": [0.0345034, 4.345345]
    }

}
```

The code I tried to make:

```
function readObject(el, data, boo) {
    for(var ind in data) { 
        el.innerHTML += '<li>';
        if (boo) {
            el.innerHTML += ind + ' - ';
        }
            console.log("another loop");
            switch (data[ind].type) {
                case "compound":
                    el.innerHTML += data[ind].type + ' - ';
                    setTimeout(function (){ readObject(el,data[ind].value,false); el.innerHTML += '</li>';},0);
                    break;
                case "string":
                    el.innerHTML += data[ind].type + ' - ';
                    el.innerHTML += data[ind].value;
                    callback();
                    break;
                case "int":
                    el.innerHTML += data[ind].type + ' - ';
                    el.innerHTML += data[ind].value;
                    callback();
                    break;
                case "long":
                    el.innerHTML += data[ind].type + ' - ';
                    el.innerHTML += data[ind].value[0] + ' - ' + data[ind].value[1];
                    callback();
                    break;
                case "list":
                    el.innerHTML += data[ind].type + ' - ';
                    el.innerHTML += data[ind].value.type + ' - ';
                    setTimeout(function (){  readObject(el,listToObject(data[ind].value),false);el.innerHTML += '</li>'; },0);
                    break;
            }



            function callback() {
                el.innerHTML += '</li>';
            }
    }
}
```

(All other types will be the same of string)

Comment: Re: "browser freezing" - [Limit DOM Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/1640/performance-tips/14978/limit-dom-updates#t=201706101834575306386)

Comment: @Emissary Thanks, I think the browser freezing is also caused by the long recursion.

Comment: It's almost certainly just because of the incremental DOM updates.  DOM operations are comparatively speaking very very slow.

Comment: @DanielBeck I've also tried a version of the function that uses var el = document.createElement(); and appending to that instead of appending to innerHTML at every move. It still froze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating the DOM is slow.

But there is also another issue with your code: you use `setTimeout`, and in the callbacks you provide to it, you reference a variable `ind` that will have changed by the time the callback is executed, leading to undesired results if any.

Your code does not produce any `ul` tags, only `li` tags. NB: You did not provide the definition of the function *listToObject*, but I assume it is not problematic (although arrays *are* objects).

Here is an implementation that will also deal well with cases where you have a list of less trivial sub types, such as "compound" -- I added an example at the end of the sample data:

```js
function objectToHtml(data, defaultType) {
    var html = '';
    for (var ind in data) {
        var item = data[ind],
            type = defaultType || item.type,
            value = defaultType ? item : item.value;
        html +=
            '<li>\n' + 
            (defaultType ? '' : ind + ' - ' + type + ' - ') +
            (type === "compound"  ? objectToHtml(value)
                : type === "list" ? value.type + ' -  ' 
                                  + objectToHtml(value.value, value.type)
                : type === "long" ? value.join(' - ')
                : value) +
            '</li>\n';
    }
    return '<ul>\n' + html + '</ul>\n';
}

// Sample data
var data = {
    "name": "",
    "value": {
        "randomname1": {
            "type": "list",
            "value": {
                "type": "int",
                "value": [26, 32, 25]
            }
        },
        "randomname2": {
            "type": "int",
            "value": 5
        },
        "randomname3": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "string or something"
        },
        "randomname4": {
            "type": "compound",
            "value": {
                "randomname5": {
                    "type": "int",
                    "value": 6
                },
                "randomname6": {
                    "type": "int",
                    "value": 6
                }
            }
        },
        "randomname7": {
            "type": "long",
            "value": [0.0345034, 4.345345]
        },
        "randomname8": {
            "type": "list",
            "value": {
                "type": "compound",
                "value": [{
                    "randomnameA": {
                        "type": "int",
                        "value": 7
                    },
                    "randomnameB": {
                        "type": "int",
                        "value": 8
                    }
                }, {
                    "randomnameC": {
                        "type": "int",
                        "value": 9
                    },
                    "randomnameD": {
                        "type": "int",
                        "value": 10
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
};


tree.innerHTML = objectToHtml(data.value);
```

```html
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Comment: This answered my question perfecly, very compact too. good job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I've exactly matched the HTML structure you're trying to create, but this should be close enough for you to modify to fit your needs.

The fastest approach is to construct a single string and drop it into the DOM, instead of doing incremental DOM operations:

```js
var convert = function(input) {
  var out = '';
  out += '<ul>';
  for (k in input) { 
    var obj = input[k];
    out += '<li>' + k + ' - ' + obj.type + ' - ';
    switch(obj.type) {
      case "compound": 
        // recurse:
        out += convert(obj.value); break;
      case "long":
        out += obj.value.join(' - '); break;
      case "list":
        out += obj.value.type + ' - ';
        out += obj.value.value.join(' - '); break;
      default:
        // looks like all the other cases are identical:
        out += obj.value;
    }
    out += '</li>';
  }
  out += '</ul>';
  return out;
}

var data = {
  "name": "",
  "value": {
    "randomname1": {
      "type": "list",
      "value": {
        "type": "int",
        "value": [26, 32, 25]
      }
    },
    "randomname2": {
      "type": "int",
      "value": 5
    },
    "randomname3": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "string or something"
    },
    "randomname4": {
      "type": "compound",
      "value": {
        "randomname5": {
          "type": "int",
          "value": 6
        },
        "randomname6": {
          "type": "int",
          "value": 6
        }
      }
    },
    "randomname7": {
      "type": "long",
      "value": [0.0345034, 4.345345]
    }
  }
};

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = convert(data.value);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Constructing this as an isolated document fragment rather than a single HTML string is, in this case, about 25% slower: https://jsperf.com/tree-test-fragment-vs-string/1

But with a little tweaking that slower method has the advantage of allowing you to use your setTimeout trick to defer each level of recursion, so the browser (one hopes) won't freeze up while trying to draw very large trees.

Here the recursion is handled in a separate function, so each setTimeout will be working with the correct data and DOM nodes (trying to do it all in the same function means that the iteration will have overwritten the variables with new data by the time the setTimeout fires -- this was part of why your original code wasn't recursing properly.) I added some deeper compound types to the data to demonstrate that this is working:

```js
var convert = function(input) {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  fragment.appendChild(ul);

  for (k in input) {
    var obj = input[k];
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var txt = k + ' - ' + obj.type + ' - ';
    if (obj.type === 'compound') {
      li.innerHTML = txt;
      recurse(li, obj.value); // acts as a closure for these vars
    } else {
      switch (obj.type) {
        case "long":
          txt += obj.value.join(' - ');
          break;
        case "list":
          txt += obj.value.type + ' - ';
          txt += obj.value.value.join(' - ');
          break;
        default:
          txt += obj.value;
      }
      li.innerHTML = txt;
    }
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  return fragment;
}

var recurse = function(li, d) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    li.appendChild(convert(d));
  }, 1);
}

var data = {
  "name": "",
  "value": {
    "randomname1": {
      "type": "list",
      "value": {
        "type": "int",
        "value": [26, 32, 25]
      }
    },
    "cptest1": {
      "type": "compound",
      "value": {
        "x": {
          "type": "int",
          "value": 2
        },
        "cptest2": {
          "type": "compound",
          "value": {
            "y": {
              "type": "int",
              "value": 2
            },
            "z": {
              "type": "int",
              "value": 3
            }
          }
        },
      }
    },
    "randomname3": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "string or something"
    },
    "randomname4": {
      "type": "compound",
      "value": {
        "randomname5": {
          "type": "int",
          "value": 6
        },
        "randomname6": {
          "type": "int",
          "value": 6
        }
      }
    },
    "randomname7": {
      "type": "long",
      "value": [0.0345034, 4.345345]
    }
  }
};

document.getElementById('output').appendChild(convert(data.value));
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```